# Php session: undefined index when using isset

Tags: php, session

I'm currently working on a simple Authentification system and i'm using PHP Sessions.

In my header of every page i have a bit of PHP that does 3 things:

- If the session last used time is older than 30 minutes it's destroyed
- If the session last used time is older than 5 minutes it's regenerated
- If the ips are not the same in the same session it's destroyed

However it doesn't seem to wok for the IP.
It gives me the error `Undefined Index` when i use isset to check if it is initialized or not.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 900) {
    // session started more than 30 minutes ago
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
//GET CHECK IP
if (!isset($_SESSION['ADDR'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['ADDR'] != get_client_ip()){
        session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    }
}else {
    $_SESSION['ADDR'] = get_client_ip();
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION)."</pre>";
```

Comment: `if (!isset($_SESSION['ADDR'])) {` I think you mean `if (isset($_SESSION['ADDR'])) {` since you're using it in that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to say if `$_SESSION['ADDR']` has **not** been set. Remove the negation operator `!`.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['ADDR'])) { 
    // code here 
}
```

Comment: I knew it must have been something so stupid! I should take a break after coding so much. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Glad to help. `:)`